# Javascript - alter conditional in recursive function

Tags: javascript

How can I make this into a recursive function:

```
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) { 
    var d = document.createElement("div"); 

    if (i % 2 != 0) {
        d.className="hide";
    }

    document.body.appendChild(d);
}

var d = document.createElement("br"); 
document.body.appendChild(d);

for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) { 
    var d = document.createElement("div"); 

    if (i % 3 != 0 || i % 2 ==0 ) {
        d.className="hide";
    }

    document.body.appendChild(d);
}

var d = document.createElement("br"); 
document.body.appendChild(d);

for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) { 
    var d = document.createElement("div"); 

    if (i % 4 != 0 || i % 3 == 0 || i % 2 ==0 ) {
        d.className="hide";
    }

    document.body.appendChild(d);
}

var d = document.createElement("br"); 
document.body.appendChild(d);
```

Each time the function is triggered the conditional should add the last condition from a != onto the chain of ==.

Maybe this is not possible with javascript?

Comment: So, just so I can make sure that I understand the problem, you want to create 3 groups of 100 `<div>` elements, each group followed by a `<br>` element.  In the first group, you want every other `<div>` to have the class name "hide", in the second and third groups, you want every other `<div>` **AND** every third `<div>` to have the class "hide" (since all numbers that are divisble by 4 are also divisible by 2, there will be no difference between the how the last two groups are created)?  Is that right?

Comment: The only difference between the three blocks of code is that the conditional changes each time. Each time a new block occurs another condition is added. That new condition is i % (the previous integer in this place +1) !=0. The condition from the previous iteration turns from inequality to equality e.g i % 4 !=0 gets changed to i % 4==0.

Comment: Okay, thanks . . . I missed that the equality/inequality operators were swapping.   Dynamically building conditions makes this a challenge to do recursively . . .

Answer (score 0):

its possible to do this
call it with function

```js
function addBody() {
 var x = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];
 for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) { 
     var d = document.createElement("div"); 
     var br = document.createElement("br"); 

     if (i % 2 != 0) {
         d.className="hide1";
     }
     else if (i % 3 != 0 || i % 2 ==0 ) {
         d.className="hide2";
     }
     else if (i % 4 != 0 || i % 3 == 0 || i % 2 ==0 ) {
         d.className="hide3";
     }
     x.appendChild(d);
     x.appendChild(br);
 }
}
```

```html
<body onload="addBody()"></body>
```

Comment: It's needs to be a recursive function!

Comment: @Kline `(i = 0; i < 100; i++)` is recursive function, tell me if i'm wrong, [read here](http://techterms.com/definition/recursivefunction)

Comment: @ntaloventi - a recursive function would call itself somewhere within it's own logic . . . so, somewhere in your `addBody()` function, you would need to make a call to `addBody()`.